# my php for sending email is not working

Tags: php, html, email

im working on a html form  where i need to send mail using php. i need to upload it in my hosting server. i uploaded these two files in the root directory. still im not able to send mail.
Here is my html code

```
<!-- form -->
<form  action="http://shankiyan.in/sendEmail.php"  method="post"  name="form" id="contactForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
    <fieldset>

        <div class="form-field">
            <input name="name" type="text" id="contactName" placeholder="Name" value="" minlength="2" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input name="email" type="email" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Email" value="" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input name="subject" type="text" id="contactSubject" placeholder="Subject" value="">
        </div>                       
        <div class="form-field">
            <textarea name="message" id="contactMessage" placeholder="message" rows="10" cols="50" required=""></textarea>
        </div>                      
        <div class="form-field">
            <button class="submitform"type="submit" name="submit" id="submitform">Submit</button>

        </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- Form End -->
```

and my php code is

```
<?php
require('sendEmail.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $formsubject=$_POST['subject'];
    $formmessage=$_POST['message'];


    $to="shmediyosel@gmail.com";
    $subject="subject:". $formsubject;
    $message="Name".$name."\n"."wrote the following".$formmessage;
    $headers="from".$email;

    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    {
        echo"<h1>message sent successfully</h1>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo"<h2> something went wrongg!</h2>";
    }


?>
```

i cant send mail from my html form .
please help me out what mistake i have done ?

Comment: where is the mail function? are you using phpmailer?

Comment: For a start: malformed headers.

Comment: Switch on error reporting and see what errors you get. It would be nice to know whether you get nothing, "message sent successfully" or "something went wrongg!" as output.

Comment: (Be warned that you are also at risk of email injection, with no filtering on user data.)

Comment: I think your problem is that your PHP script 'sendEmail.php' `requires()` itself, or at least that seems weird.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: something went wrong is my error

Comment: @romaltandel im using nothing just these two files alone . i dont know anything about these mail function

Comment: Check php.ini to see if mail() function is enabled on your server (or use a php lib for send emails)

Comment: where do i check php.ini file @Roy

Comment: Create a .php file with **<?php phpinfo(); ?>** on it, call it in a browser and check the function mail()

Comment: the same code  <?php phpinfo(); ?>  is coming  if i call it in a browser @Roy

Comment: Call it via server... http://www.your-server.com/folder/nameOfFile.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158602/discussion-between-shankiyan-shanki-and-roy).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this code on the top of your php file and check for any errors:

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Also, is the sendEmail.php requiring itself? Because this will not work.

If not, can you provide us with the sendEmail.php so we can understand easier the problem?